# Self-modifying Hamiltonians (Lagrangians) and emerging intelligence?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, computational-physics, spin-models

Are there dynamical physical systems that are governed by self-modifying Hamiltonians (Lagrangians), i.e. Hamiltonians (Lagrangians) determine not only the next point in phase space, but also the form of Hamiltonian (Lagrangian) in the next time step. Can concrete example of such system be provided.

I have heard that spin glasses can be used for modelling neural networks. Spin glasses are described by Hamiltonians. Maybe such self-modifying Hamiltonians can be used for describing self-modifying (evolving) neural networks with emergence of intelligence in them.

Comment: This sounds like too vague of a question to answer. For example, I suppose you could think of a mass on a spring as a system that "self-modifies" the force from the spring to keep the mass oscillating. But what do you gain from that?

Comment: The whole post seems to be reasoning from vague word association ("neural networks" = "spin glasses" = "Hamiltonians" so "intelligence" = "self-modifying Hamiltonian"). What specifically do you want to know?

Comment: There is notion of Goedel machine http://people.idsia.ch/~juergen/goedelmachine.html, neural networks can be physical realization of this machine (it is already proved that neural networks can simulate Turing machine) and this realization can be simulated using spin glasses. So - what physical systems (Hamilatonians, Lagrangians) can lead to emergence of intelligence in spin glasses? For mathematical description of consciousness see IIT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_information_theory

Comment: But almost everything can simulate a Turing machine. You can make a Turing machine in Super Mario. What specifically about your question applies to spin glasses but not the Italian plumber?

Comment: I am interested in neural networks and spin glasses is THE model that simulates them. I don't know how Mario can simulate neural networks. And one uses Hamiltonian formalisms for spin glasses.

Comment: I will consider the system you propose seriously. The system has a state $\vec{z}$. The time step is a map $\vec{z}' = \vec{\zeta}(\vec{z})$. The "self-improvement" is a change of some internal parameters $\vec{w}$ of the map $\vec{\zeta}$. Let me write this self-improvement rule as $\vec{w}' = \vec{\omega}(\vec{w}, \vec{z}')$. However, we can write this as a single dynamical system on the space of states $\vec{w},\vec{z}$ with a step $(\vec{w}',\vec{z}') = (\vec{\omega}(\vec{w},\vec{\zeta}(\vec{z})), \vec{\zeta}(\vec{z}))$.

Comment: You can now see that the classification of the system as "self-improving" is only formal. In physical literature one would never use the term "self-improving", the parameters of the map $\vec{w}$ would simply always be seen as dynamical variables.